# Google Photos API on Android without Server

Tags: android, google-photos-api

I'm pretty new to Android / mobile programming.

Is it possible to create an Android App that talks directly to the Google Photos API without my own server / backend? I see most of the examples have a Java server, but for the simple app I'm trying to build, I don't want/need the extra server.

In particular, the part I'm struggling with is obtaining Credentials used in this class [1] from Android. I can't figure out how to get a refresh token, and the included code on github does not run on Android (only on a server).

[1] https://github.com/google/java-photoslibrary/blob/a26b5de8924b68158d759a478af425f267a344a8/sample/src/main/java/com/google/photos/library/sample/factories/PhotosLibraryClientFactory.java

Thanks!

Comment: you don't need anything except a Google Cloud Account with Enabled PHOTOS API and a serial key

Comment: Right, I already did that to get the Google sign in working, but I can't get a refresh token from that. The refresh token is required to instantiate UserCredentials, which is required to create the PhotosLibraryClient